# cambiar color de icono al estar en focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo el siguiente codigo html con bootstrap 4.

```
 <div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i></span>
      <input type="text" id="log-user" name="log-user" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Usuario" required>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="input-group pt-3">
   <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash fa-sm"></i></span>
     <input type="password" id="clave-user" name="clave-user" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Contraseña">
 </div>
</div>
```

lo que necesito es que al tener foco en los input cambie tambien el color de la etiqueta i, o en su defecto el span..
he tratado con lo siguiente pero sin resultado..

```
.input-group>input:focus + span>i{
   color: blue;
}
tambien use:
.input-group input:focus + span{
    color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrás que utilizar un poquito de javascript.

```js
$(':input').focusin(function(){

    var wrapper = $(this).parent().find('span');
    $('span').css({'border':'none'});
    wrapper.css({'border':'1px solid red'});


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i>a</span>
      <input type="text" id="log-user" name="log-user" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Usuario" required>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="input-group pt-3">
   <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash fa-sm"></i>b</span>
     <input type="password" id="clave-user" name="clave-user" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Contraseña">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono muy perfecto solo que tube que hacer una parte para cuando deja de tener foco, ya que me mantenia el color que le estoy asignando           $(':input').blur(function() {
        var wrapper = $(this).parent().find('span');
        $('span').css({ 'color': 'none' });
        wrapper.css({ 'color': 'green' });
    });

Answer (score 2):

Considero que con CSS no vas a alcanzar a lograrlo, pero con JS puedes hacerlo así:

- Asignamos un *listener* al contenedor `div` principal donde existen los inputs y las etiquetas i
- Verificamos con un if/else si el elemento que generó el evento click tiene determinado id y en concencuencia asignamos el color a cada i
- Como solo son 2 elementos puedes tenerlos almacenados en una variable y acceder al elemento deseado por medio de la [posicion] que ocupa

**Ejemplo**

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user fa-lg">1</i></span>
        <input type="text" id="log-user" name="log-user" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Usuario" required>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group pt-3">
     <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash fa-sm">2</i></span>
       <input type="password" id="clave-user" name="clave-user" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Contraseña">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  let contenedor = document.querySelector(".contenedor")
  let etiquetasI = document.querySelectorAll(".fas")
  
  contenedor.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {
    if(evento.target.id === "log-user") {
      etiquetasI[0].style.color = "crimson"
      etiquetasI[1].style.color = "initial"
    } else {
      etiquetasI[1].style.color = "yellow"
      etiquetasI[0].style.color = "initial"
    }
  })
</script>
```